# Tech Writing: What to call list columns?

Tags: copywriting, wording, documentation, technical-writing

I'm currently re-writing some software documentation for users, and I'm stuck on how to label the columns on this page, which lists files that you've recently exported from the system, with various columns to describe the file. In the old documentation they are called "Features," which sounds pretty inaccurate to me, but a better word is escaping me. Thanks for any help you can give.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a single word describing "Export schedule", "Created", "Start", "Duration" and so on? What about "Details", or more explicit "Exported file details"?

Comment: I'm looking for some way to describe the page and its sections e.g. "On this page you will see a list of all files exported in the last seven days and the details of each file: Export schedule, Created, etc..." Details definitely sounds better than features.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I've posted an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Based on brief discussion with the OP I'm posting an official answer:

**Details** is the word you are looking for.
For more explicit information it would be **"Exported files details"**.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say attributes or details, but prefer attributes. Features could be a synonym for attributes or details, but since features tends to have a certain connotation in software development, I think attributes or details have a more agnostic tone. I prefer attributes because it indicates specific characteristics, whereas details sounds more generic to me (like "stuff" does).

Comment: Could you expand on your answer a bit? Right now it reads more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Edited my answer to be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Usually those are called "file attributes" (at least the more standard ones like created timestamp and file size), so "attributes" is another option.

Answer (score 0):

The bit of information missing from the question is who the documentation is for, so:

- If the documentation is for IT-literate users, "attributes" probably works (although I tend to think of those sorts of things as properties of the file)
- If for novice users, instead of "details of the files", try "information about the files".

Just suggestions!